# Update GPG error - NO_PUBKEY - The repository release is not signed

Tags: apt, updates

I'm having some issues updating Ubuntu 18.04. Here is the error output

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Researching similar problems, for example

[How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Doesn't work. Specifically, I get the error

```
nik@nik:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.uWb8bIzMR8/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data

nik@nik:~$ gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2F7F0DA5FD5B64B9
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No data
```

I couldn't find a working solution to that problem though. Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the offending repository from my repository list.